# who to read .git-ci.yml file

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm very new to the Git lab, try to understand the .gitlab-ci.yml file. i would be thanksfull if someone could help me with this, what will all this command do, and where it will be installed all this packages, inside a docker container?

```
staging:
  stage: staging
  script:
    - apt-get update -qy
    - apt-get install -y ruby-dev
    - gem install dpl
    - dpl --provider=heroku --app=$HEROKU_STAGING_APP --api-key=$HEROKU_STAGING_API_KEY --skip-cleanup
  only:
    - main
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to explain.

**.git-ci.yml** is the default file which would be read by GitLab for creation and execution of the pipeline whenever there are changes in the repository (new commit, new branch, new tag etc)

Now regarding the specific to the question, this defines a job which would be executed as part of **staging** stage, actual sequence would depend on how many stages are defined in your file and where this staging appears in the sequence. (Please refer **stages:** in your file.

Now by default all the jobs will be run on the runner. These runners are identified by the tags, as I don't see any tags in your particular job its bit difficult to comment on.

You may have an explicit image tag in your job for e.g.  **image: openjdk:17-alpine** to run the job on a particular container.

So, whatever commands are written in the script: block, would get executed on

- Either the runner where the job would be launched
- Or, the container launched by using the image tag

I hope, it help you to understand the basic execution.